# netbeans won't start after pc hung while installing plugin

Tags: java, netbeans

I've just installed a plugin (Python) on NetBeans 6.9 - during that time my Ubuntu Natty nearly froze; unfortunately it seems to do that whenever there are too many file operations 
happening.

I now find that NetBeans won't start.

```
Log Session: Friday, May 20, 2011 10:52:37 PM CEST
System Info: 
  Product Version         = NetBeans IDE 6.9 (Build 100825-unknown-revn)
  Operating System        = Linux version 2.6.38-8-generic running on i386
  Java; VM; Vendor        = 1.6.0_22; OpenJDK Client VM 20.0-b11; Sun Microsystems Inc.
  Runtime                 = OpenJDK Runtime Environment 1.6.0_22-b22
  Java Home               = /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre
  System Locale; Encoding = de_DE (nb); UTF-8
  Home Directory          = /home/flo
  Current Directory       = /home/flo
  User Directory          = /home/flo/.netbeans/6.9
  Installation            = /usr/share/netbeans/6.9/nb
                            /usr/share/netbeans/6.9/ide
                            /usr/share/netbeans/6.9/java
                            /usr/share/netbeans/6.9/apisupport
                            /usr/share/netbeans/6.9/harness
                            /usr/share/netbeans/6.9/platform
  Boot & Ext. Classpath   = /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/lib/j
vm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/rt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar:/usr
/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/jce.jar:/us
r/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/netx.j
ar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/rhino.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/modules/jdk.boot.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/classes:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/ext/pulse-java.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/ext/gnome-java-bridge.jar
  Application Classpath   = /usr/share/java/log4j-1.2.jar:/usr/share/netbeans/6.9/platform/lib/boot.jar:/usr/share/netbeans/6.9/platform/lib/org-openide-modules.jar:/usr/share/netbeans/6.9/platform/lib/org-openide-util.jar:/usr/share/netbeans/6.9/platform/lib/org-openide-util-lookup.jar:/usr/share/netbeans/6.9/platform/lib/locale/boot_ja.jar:/usr/share/netbeans/6.9/platform/lib/locale/boot_pt_BR.jar:/usr/share/netbeans/6.9/platform/lib/locale/boot_zh_CN.jar:/usr/share/netbeans/6.9/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-modules_ja.jar:/usr/share/netbeans/6.9/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-modules_pt_BR.jar:/usr/share/netbeans/6.9/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-modules_zh_CN.jar:/usr/share/netbeans/6.9/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util_ja.jar:/usr/share/netbeans/6.9/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util-lookup_ja.jar:/usr/share/netbeans/6.9/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util-lookup_pt_BR.jar:/usr/share/netbeans/6.9/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util-lookup_zh_CN.jar:/usr/share/netbeans/6.9/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util_pt_BR.jar:/usr/share/netbeans/6.9/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util_zh_CN.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/lib/dt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/lib/tools.jar
  Startup Classpath       = /usr/share/netbeans/6.9/platform/core/core.jar:/usr/share/netbeans/6.9/platform/core/org-openide-filesystems.jar:/usr/share/netbeans/6.9/platform/core/locale/org-openide-filesystems_pt_BR.jar:/usr/share/netbeans/6.9/platform/core/locale/core_ja.jar:/usr/share/netbeans/6.9/platform/core/locale/core_pt_BR.jar:/usr/share/netbeans/6.9/platform/core/locale/core_zh_CN.jar:/usr/share/netbeans/6.9/platform/core/locale/org-openide-filesystems_ja.jar:/usr/share/netbeans/6.9/platform/core/locale/org-openide-filesystems_zh_CN.jar:/usr/share/netbeans/6.9/nb/core/org-netbeans-upgrader.jar:/usr/share/netbeans/6.9/nb/core/locale/org-netbeans-upgrader_pt_BR.jar:/usr/share/netbeans/6.9/nb/core/locale/org-netbeans-upgrader_zh_CN.jar:/usr/share/netbeans/6.9/nb/core/locale/core_nb_ja.jar:/usr/share/netbeans/6.9/nb/core/locale/core_nb_zh_CN.jar:/usr/share/netbeans/6.9/nb/core/locale/core_nb.jar:/usr/share/netbeans/6.9/nb/core/locale/org-netbeans-upgrader_ja.jar:/usr/share/netbeans/6.9/nb/core/locale/core_nb_pt_BR.jar
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
WARNING [org.netbeans.core.startup.ModuleList]
java.io.EOFException
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(ObjectInputStream.java:2570)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1314)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:368)
        at org.netbeans.core.startup.ModuleList.readCache(Unknown Source)
        at org.netbeans.core.startup.ModuleList$ReadInitial.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.openide.filesystems.EventControl.runAtomicAction(Unknown Source)
        at org.openide.filesystems.FileSystem.runAtomicAction(Unknown Source)
        at org.netbeans.core.startup.ModuleList.readInitial(Unknown Source)
        at org.netbeans.core.startup.ModuleSystem.readList(Unknown Source)
        at org.netbeans.core.startup.Main.getModuleSystem(Unknown Source)
        at org.netbeans.core.startup.Main.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.netbeans.core.startup.TopThreadGroup.run(Unknown Source)
[catch] at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
INFO [org.netbeans.core.startup.NbEvents]: Turning on modules:
        org.openide.util.lookup [8.3.1 100825-unknown-revn]
        org.openide.util [8.6.1 100825-unknown-revn]
        org.openide.modules [7.17.1 100825-unknown-revn]
        org.openide.filesystems [7.38.1 100825-unknown-revn]
        org.netbeans.upgrader [4.14.1 100820-unknown-revn]
        org.netbeans.bootstrap/1 [2.33.1 100825-unknown-revn]
        org.netbeans.core.startup/1 [1.25.1 100825-unknown-revn]
```

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if Ubuntu provides Netbeans plugins as packages, however if it does, and that's the way you've installed this plugin, you may purge (`apt-get purge`) the package and install it again.
If it doesn't help, only reasonable way would be to delete Netbeans data folders (get them back to state of fresh installation) - that's the way I'm used to when dealing with such a problems. Netbeans is way to complicated to edit it's configuration files by hand.